# Scenario when one may be requiring custom class loader?

Tags: java, jvm

I am looking for a simple scenario when can be requirement to create a custom class loader?

Apart from that, just wanted to confirm that Does even bootstrap and application class loader extends java.lang.ClassLoader internally?

Comment: Well a Java application server such as tomcat might require a custom class loader, for such things as giving each application it's own "snapshot" of loaded classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, it can be used to add new code or to change existing code on the fly. Here's a more detailed explanation from this [URL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/id1100.html).

Why write a custom class loader?

The three main reasons for wanting to create a custom class loader are:

- To allow class loading from alternative repositories.

  This is the most common case, in which an application developer might want to load classes from other locations, for example, over a network connection.
- To partition user code.

  This case is less frequently used by application developers, but widely used in servlet engines.
- To allow the unloading of classes.

  This case is useful if the application creates large numbers of classes that are used for only a finite period. Because a class loader maintains a cache of the classes that it has loaded, these classes cannot be unloaded until the class loader itself has been dereferenced. For this reason, system and extension classes are never unloaded, but application classes can be unloaded when their classloader is.

Comment: Thanks RHT. As you said "application classes can be unloaded when their classloader is." Does application class loader gets unloaded anytime in app/web server. As per myunderstanding they will unloaded also when we shutdown the app/web server.Right? Not sure what does  extension classes mean?

Comment: Hi Sach. First of all I apologize for the late response. I returned to StackOverflow today, looking for my own response to this question and I noticed your comment.

Comment: Your question - What are system / extension classes deserves to be a separate top level question on StackOverflow and it merits a detailed response, but in short - Application Server itself it a java application which sits on top of a JVM therefore it has it's own system classes that it needs to use or libraries that it may share across different applications. Terminology varies from one vendor to another but such classes are not unloaded with the application.